# How to get acceleration of a vehicle in veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am using `veins-4.5` `omnet++ 5` and `sumo 0.29.0`.
How can I access the *acceleration* of a vehicle in veins?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Another alternative is to switch to the VENTOS simulator. It has already implemented vehicleGetAcceleration. More information here: http://maniam.github.io/VENTOS/

Answer (score 1):

As of SUMO 0.29.0, acceleration is not one of the [variables exposed by the SUMO TraCI API of a vehicle](http://www.sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Vehicle_Value_Retrieval) - primarily because it is not one of the state variables of the most common car following models.

You will need to compute acceleration yourself, by comparing the current speed of a vehicle to its speed before the last update.

Note that there is more than one way of deriving acceleration from speed, depending on what you assume about the underlying process. For more details, there is [a 2015 paper by Treiber and Kanagaraj](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.4881) that discusses this.